# Order of z-index elements on bxslider

Tags: jquery, css, z-index, bxslider

I need to order the contents of a bxslider with a no-child element. between the image and the text over the top.

e.g

```
<div>
<ul id="slider">
<li><img src="image1.jpg" /><span>text</span></li>
</ul>
<div class="under-text-over-image"></div>
</div>
```

Could anyone advise on the z-index?

my existing css is similar to:

```
li img{
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}
li span{
position:relative;
z-index:3;
}
.under-text-over-image{
position:relative;
z-index:2;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: "I have seemed to try everything" So, what have you tried?

Comment: Please see the question text

Comment: Is/Are parent(s) positionned: position:relative?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something along the lines of:

```
li img{
position:relative;
z-index:-99999;
}

li span{
position:relative;
z-index:99999;
}

.under-text-over-image{
position:relative;
z-index:11111;
}
```

something along these lines, usually works for me when using z-index.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

My late reply... BXSlider has zIndexing within the JS (read more here: http://bxslider.com/docs/jquery.bxslider.html). The best way I have found to get around the flicker in any slide, whatever direction it appears in is if you nest your content inside the `<ul>` within another `<div>`. In my experiments, this seems to cause no distracting reordering of the visible or unwanted invisible layers.

Here's an example for your slides:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
<li>
    <div style="position:absolute;z-index:88888;">
        ... this content will be above everything else ...
    </div>
</li>
    <li>
    <div style="position:absolute;z-index:88888;">
        ... this content will be also be above ...
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Note: z-index needs a position declaration to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but the issue does come up quite a bit it seems. The issue isn't z-indexing:

**You're most likely missing the image files**

```
bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
  left: 10px;
  background: url(images/controls.png) no-repeat 0 -32px;
}
```

**A quick check**

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Once you do this you'll see that the controls are there.