# Z-Index of elements in Adobe Edge always 0?

Tags: jquery, z-index, adobe-edge

I'm tearing my hair out here a bit, and finding the API documentation for edge to be not amazing.. Anyway, I've got a project set up with a bunch of stuff on the stage, and I just want to find out what order everything is in like so:

```
var stage = sym.getComposition.getStage();
var children = stage.getChildSymbols();

for( var i = 0; i < children.length; ++i )
{
   alert( children[i].getSymbolElement().css( "z-index" ) );
}
```

But everything seems to have z-index as 0, and I have no idea how else to find out the order in which everything is drawn.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, a member of Adobe staff let me know that I can't actually access the z index of stuff I've placed in Edge Animate. But, I was able to achieve what I wanted by doing the following `var dom = sym.getComposition().symbolDefns[sym.getSymbolTypeName()].content.dom;
for( var i = 0; i < dom.length; ++i )
{
// etc
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Adobe staff got back to me about this, and they told me that symbols which are laid out in the editor (and not dynamically created) are ordered using an internal index which is not exposed to be modified or even read. I'll have to find another way!

Answer (score 0):

Wild stab in the dark (I know *nothing* about Adobe Edge), but in CSS `z-index` is irrelevant to statically-positioned content, and effectively treated as `0`. So if all of your elements are statically positioned, that would explain why they all say `0`.

From [the CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index):

> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in back-to-front order:
>   
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
>   
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
>   
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
>   
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
>   
> 5. the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.
>   
> 6. the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0.
>   
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

As you can see, #3 in the above (which occurs between elements with negative stacking values and positive ones, e.g., at `0`) applies to elements with the default `position`, which is `static`. So in effect, `z-index` only applies to `position: relative`, `position: absolute`, etc. elements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Edge, but in Flash the z value is how far or close it is in space (I think). I don't think it's the same thing as order inside a layer. Perhaps try to find a variable called "order", "arrangement", "layer" or something to do with arrangement order.

Perhaps this will help: [Order of z-index elements on bxslider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297105/order-of-z-index-elements-on-bxslider)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this program is not using z-index for managing order of layers. Order of layers is made probably during dynamic creation of js code - ordering form bottom.

If you want to use z-index you must first define manually z-index of your div(s) and then change it and get value.

Set z-index:

```
div.css({"z-index":"123"});
```

Get z-index:

```
div.css("z-index");
```

Comment: You can see my comment on the original question for a possible workaround.