# Scrolling div tags on touch?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, I have got a number div tags, within a section tag and on selected menu button clicks scrolls though to that selected div area.

Each div area has a `translate3d` css, move each div out one other the other. Then the code fires on a 'click' event to move the div tag into the browser window.

CSS code

```
#Area1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
    border-left:10px solid #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    background-color: #66cc33;
    -moz-transform:translate3d(100%,0%,0px) skew(16deg, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0%,0px) skew(16deg, 0);
}
```

Area2 code would be the same, but set at 200%. This div tag is set within a div wrapper set with position relative on it.

Jquery code the moves the div

```
  $( "#AreaOne" ).animate({left: "0%"}, 1000, 'easeInOutQuad');
  $( "#AreaTwo" ).delay(100).animate({left: "0%"}, 1000, 'easeInOutQuad');
```

This all works fine. No problems at all. But I want to be able to swipe through these divs as well. But is does not do this on my iphone I am testing on. Now I think this is because I use an click event function? I don't really want to change the code I have made, mainly because it works fine.

Now I tried using touchwipe on the div, but that did not work, not sure if I call it in right or not :).

Just wanted to know if there was a quick a simple way of making a div scroll on touch?

Many thanks,

Glenn.

PS. Sorry if I have not explained myself well. If its not clear, please let me know and I will change my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the web-kit specific declaration?

```
overflow-y: scroll; /* has to be scroll, not auto */
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* momentum scrolling, iOS Safari only*/
```

More depth here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements/

Also see the documentation for [-webkit-overflow-scrolling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling).

Comment: If I understand you right, and no I did not think about that, I add this to each div tag or to the parent div tag the areas tags are set in?

Comment: Plus, this would add a scroll bar by setting the overflow to scroll, something that I dont really want to happen. I just want to touch scroll though them, rather than click.

Comment: Ok, well please try it and let us know. Also without a fiddle, I'm second guessing you might need to refer to this for the parent elements: `pointer-events: none;` http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

Comment: I did try this and it did not work, but I think it might, I have the divs that I am trying to scroll though on a z-index lower than that of the parent div! So I think that might be why it did not work. But this is on pause for now has the site is being re-designed for mobile. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well as it happens, just a few days ago I experimented with the z-index of nested `<div>` elements in the `<li>` have a look at my snippet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297105/order-of-z-index-elements-on-bxslider/22459838#22459838

I hope this is useful.